# lapply on two list vectors

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists p

```
p <- list(1:5,4:8,7:11)
```

and another list of lists

```
q <- list(2:3,1:2,4:5)
```

I want to set for each list in p and a corresponding list in q,

```
p[q] <- Inf;
```

For instance, 
(1:5) [2:3] <- Inf, (4:8) [1:2] <- inf, and (7:11) [4:5] <- Inf;

How can I achieve that? The end result of the function would be updated list of lists. Thanks.

Comment: These are two lists of vectors, not lists of lists.

Answer (score 5):

**mapply / [<-**

```
> mapply("[<-", p, q, Inf, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
[[1]]
[1]   1 Inf Inf   4   5

[[2]]
[1] Inf Inf   6   7   8

[[3]]
[1]   7   8   9 Inf Inf
```

**mapply / replace**

```
mapply(replace, p, q, Inf, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

**lapply / replace**

```
lapply(seq_along(p), function(i) replace(p[[i]], q[[i]], Inf))
```

**for**

```
for(i in seq_along(p)) p[[i]][ q[[i]] ] <- Inf
```

**replace / melt**

If each component of `p` has the same length (as the example in the question does) we can turn `p` into a data.frame which opens up additional possibilities.  This returns a data frame:

```
library(reshape2)
replace(as.data.frame(p), as.matrix(melt(q)), Inf)
```

**vapply / replace**

This also assumes that each component of `p` has the same length returning a matrix:

```
vapply(seq_along(p), function(i) replace(p[[i]], q[[i]], Inf), 0 * p[[1]])
```

*REVISED* Minor improvements plus alternatives.

Comment: you're scraping from my answer and alexis' comment a little, no? i could expect that from a newbie but you?

Comment: I didn't see any of that until I had already answered.  These responses are all within minutes of each other.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
p <- Map(`[<-`, p, q, Inf)
```

Maybe easier to understand is the longer equivalent version

```
p <- mapply(function(x, y, z) {x[y] <- z; x}, p, q, Inf, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: Or, maybe, even easier to understand could be `Map(replace, p, q, Inf)`? :-)

Comment: @flodel can you explain what does [<- mean here? Thanks.

Comment: `"[<-"` is the function being called when you do `a[i] <- b`. The latter is syntactic sugar for `"[<-"(a, i, b)`.